# Interview follow up after first round

Tags: interviewing, follow-up, email-etiquette

I just finished an interview with an employee from a mixed-signal team which was scheduled for 30 minutes. The interview was split as a)background of the company b)my experience+motivations to switch roles c)whiteboard drawing of one of my circuits+challenges d)questions from me.

I did not have a lot of relevant experience, my background is more analog but I did have some PLL experience. However the circuit I worked on was based on a very new and experimental architecture at the time so I thought if I delved into it, it would take a lot of time, and I had maybe 15 minutes left. So I picked a simpler circuit and worked through it.

At the end I asked all my questions and he just said if I had any more questions I could email him. I got nervous and did not ask about next steps, and neither did he say anything specific. I had also gotten distracted a little because his kid wandered in so I became conscious of time running out.

Is him not mentioning next steps a bad thing? Would it help to follow up with him later today or tomorrow? I have been overthinking this a lot so any sane answers would help.

Answer (score 2):

It's important not to overthink things.

The interviewer was probably doing a few interviews that day, potentially was juggling their day-to-day job, while apparently caring for their child. They probably had a lot going on in their head.

It's also a possibility that there was an assumption that someone else was guiding you through the process. When I was an interviewer, I would just conduct the interview and HR would organise the entire process. I wasn't even aware of timelines or how the candidate was to be informed.

There is no harm in sending a thank-you email, and taking that moment to inquire about the next steps in the process.

Answer (score 1):

> Is him not mentioning next steps a bad thing?

Maybe yes, maybe no. There is  no way of knowing.

> Would it help to follow up with him later today or tomorrow?

A quick thank you note is fine.  If you are really interested in the role, you should state this in the thank you note (if you haven't already). Something like "I really enjoyed our meeting and I hope we can continue conversation" is fine.

If you don't hear anything for a week (which is likely), a quick follow up inquiring about next steps would be approbriate.

> I have been overthinking this

Yes, you do. Relax. This is still very early in the game: you only had one 30-minute screen. The hiring manager will be doing 5-10 more of these before they will go to the next step. You maybe in the next round or not: at this point you can only wait it out.

This is all perfectly normal for job a search. Sometimes you get an offer and sometimes you don't.